# Why doesn't my Like button register any clicks on a cloned site?

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, addthis

I have two sites running from the same repository: http://somedemands.org/, and http://someactions.org/. I'm using the host headers to apply the variations between the two, and I'm a little baffled why the like button on Some Actions isn't registering any likes at all.

When I click on it myself and refresh the page, it should show at least one "like," but does not. It still shows the unclicked button. Note that it works perfectly on Some Demands.

The other dev on the site ran it through the lint tool on the developer site, fixed all the issues, but still no dice.

Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your `og:url` tags on someactions.org have the other domain name `somedemands.org` instead of the `someactions.org`.

Example:
http://someactions.org/2/shop-with-local-merchants-instead-of-national-multinational-chains

has the og:url
  `<meta property="og:url" content="http://somedemands.org/2/shop-with-local-merchants-instead-of-national-multinational-chains" />`

Comment: Good catch, but the index page didn't have that problem. I changed what you suggested anyway though.